# Spring boot websocket handing binary and text messages

Tags: spring-websocket

How can you handle binary and text websocket messages in Spring Boot?

I can only register one handler to a url path.  If I try to register a binary and a text handler then no messages are handled.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@ComponentScan("org.ets.llafrontend.controllers")
public class WebSocketConfig2 implements WebSocketConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private WebsocketText textHandler;

    @Autowired
    private WebsocketBinary binaryHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(textHandler, "/websocket");
//        registry.addHandler(binaryHandler, "/websocket");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that TextWebSocketHandler can handle binary and text messages via handleTextMessage and handleBinaryMessage, it just is not in the documentation.